# Compiling from remix onto geth console

Tags: compilation, console, bytecode

I found how to deploy a contract onto MEW, but I do not understand, partially due to meta references and missing/assumed knowledge.  I'm just looking from help on a walk through.  I'm including the instructions (from [medium.com](https://medium.com/@prashantprabhakarsingh/deploying-contract-using-bytecode-myetherwallet-and-remix-10f643a82d40)) with my questions

Compiling on remix.  I have an import, do need both the compiled import file or just the byteCode from the file that imported that file

I assume I should save the byteCode to one file and abi to another.  Can I edit any of the files first to bypass the passing argument?  Also do I (linux user with actual geth, not MM), type in "geth console " (then each of these):

```
var abi = abi_provided_by_remix;
var rowByteCode = "byte_code_provided_by_remix";
```

(these two are where I am asking about copying to files above)

```
var myContract = eth.contract(abi);
```

(is this  meta-reference, or explicit?)

```
var byteCodeWithParam = myContract.new.getData(param1,param2,{data: rowByteCode});
```

A few questions about the last line: 
Do I have to go through the code and type in every parameter?
How do I know I didn't miss anything?
How are these separated from exercised functions performed after compile, like transfer?
What about values defined later in the contract?

Last question about the last command, is "data: rowByteCode" a meta-reference or explicit?)

Finally where is the output to copy to MEW deploy contract box?

Please don't tell me, "It's easier if you use (insert software here)."  For one reason or another, it really isn't; sorry.  For example, I only have eth in one account, but I don't have json/utc files for it, making other tools not an option